# Windows 7 CMD tracert gives totally different final IP to online traceroute

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, networking

So, i'm pretty damn rusty with this stuff, and been up all night for client emergency, so excuse me if i'm typing gibberish and didn't find related search results./

I'm suddenly taking over a clients site after many years of not taking on any client sites, and suddenly trying to get up to speed. in trying to track down where his server and mail hosting (bcoz clients IT guy's gone AWOL, and site's down).

If I traceroute online at NT (http://network-tools.com/) I get an end result of: lag41.sclarinte01.aapt.net.au (202.10.14.201)

If I tracert the same domain from Windows 7 CMD I get: remus.instanthosting.com.au [210.8.91.130]

NT shows the mail & site resolving to: lag41.sclarinte01.aapt.net.au (202.10.14.201) , which makes sense.

The Windows CMD Mail times out, which makes no sence because it's working, but the site is not.

I understand the Trace starts from completely different places, but why do they end up at completely different places?

Comment: The site might be using some CDN that distributes resources so that the geologically closest server is used to fetch the resources. That is why the IP address fails.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yet both the results are in Sydney AU, it looks like the same datacentre, but the results/ip are different?

Comment: Another question where the real domain name is omitted or obfuscated (for what reason I don't know), making it difficult to provide any answer that might be helpful.

Comment: Ok, domain specialistcosmeticsurgery.com.au

Comment: Your site is visible from where I live, and network-tools trace ends at remus.instanthosting.com.au.

Comment: Ok, i'm now seeing the same - previously the site was down - 2 different results from Windows and NT, now the site is up the show the same. I'm interested why this is?

Comment: Check http://www.intodns.com/specialistcosmeticsurgery.com.au

Comment: I still don't understand why I got completely different results for:
A) online NT tracerout
B) Windows CMD traceroute
Could this simply be explained by DNS caching in different parts of the world (Given the host was having a complete outage)?